# zenbook ux5304va has no sound from internal speakers on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, asus, bios, acpi

the lots of zenbooks has similar issue with no sound from internal speakers on all linux distros not just ubuntu due to lack of ACPI entries in the BIOS (we can only hope that Asus updates the BIOS with correct ACPI, but they aren't supporting Linux, only Windows, and for some reason on Windows sound is working).

My laptop is **zenbook_s13_ux5304va**, I've tried patch from similar laptop: https://gist.github.com/lamperez/862763881c0e1c812392b5574727f6ff but had no success.

I've also tried expermental **6.5-rc2** kernel from ubuntu, didn't worked.

Has anyone been able to run the sound on zenbook_s13_ux5304va maybe? please share the guide on how to do that.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed it with custom GRUB SSDT Patch which provides the missing ACPI, however patch doesn't work with modifications to linux kernel (I've also posted info of what needs to be added to kernel to make patch worked)

Fix posted in github: https://github.com/badgers-ua/asus_zenbook_ux5304va_sound

Answer (score 1):

I have GREAT news!

I upgraded my kernel in Ubuntu to the latest bleeding edge, 6.7.4, released yesterday on 5 February 2024, and to my amazement, the internal speakers of my Asus Zenbook S13 OLED started magically working!

Here’s how I did it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install -y mainline
sudo mainline
```

It should grab and compile the latest kernel. It took about 30 minutes on my Zenbook.

Then reboot. You should have both the native Ubuntu kernel and your new mainline kernel in the grub menu.

---

Here’s the actual kernel commit for adding support for the Asus Zenbook  speakers (added on 12 Nov 2023)… https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=713f040cd22285fcc506f40a0d259566e6758c3c

Comment: Kind of brave, I mean who knows what else might break (especially on a machine used for develoment).

Answer (score 0):

Install `alsamixer`, and just play around with it until sound works. Select different devices, channels, I have oone in which I had to mute `engineering mode`. With alsamixer, you'll get it working. But you could try `gnome control center` first. It's really  simple.

Comment: Already tried, unfortunately it doesnt work, both alsamixer and gnome control center are recognizing the device but no sound playing the problem of why it isn't working also described here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215993#c27

Comment: If you're comparing gnome-control-center to alsa mixer then you didn't get very far with the latter.  It would takkke me an hour to go through alsa mixer. If it's a really new lappy, there mightt not be a module yet. Use `lsmod` to check what is loaded with 'Intel hda`